# record not loaded on time to compute property in a component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Component:

```
{{foods-table foods=model}}
```

receives foods attribute from outer scope.

This component has a computed property:

```
saturatedSum: function() {

var sum = this.get('foods').reduce(function(previousValue, food, index){
    return previousValue + food.get("saturated");
}, 0);

return sum;

}.property('foods.@each')  //key @each instructs to update bindings
```

I'm using this component twice, once in meals route and once in meals.findFood route. **First component instance renders {{saturatedSum}} as NAN** and **second component gives appropriate numerical sum.**

I'm assuming record associated with attribute passed from outer scope is not fully loaded before reduction (`this.get('foods').get('length')` will return 4, but `this.get('foods').objectAt(0).get('saturated')` will be undefined.

**What is the elegant way to deal with this?**

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with:

```
saturatedSum: 0

_updateSaturatedSum: ->
  @setProperty 'saturatedSum', 0
  @get('foods').then (foods) =>
    foods.forEach (food) =>
      food.then (loadedFood) =>
        @incrementProperty 'saturatedSum', loadedFood.get('saturated')

updateSaturatedSum: (->
  Em.run.throttle @, '_updateSaturatedSum', 500
).observes('foods.@each').on('init')
```

Comment: You have pointed me in the right direction. This.get('foods') will return object that may or may not have `then` method, so probably would need a check like `if (!this.get('foods').isLoaded) ` which would return !undefined when records are not yet fulfilled.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware that you're promises are fullfilled inside `reduce` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @Daniel has pointed me in the right direction:

using `property('foods@each')` method on computed function was already providing updated bindings. But this binding was focused on `foods@each` (eg. observer was triggered only when number of foods has changed.

What we wanted is to be aware of changes that cause saturated attribute to change.

Hence **most elegant solution** seems to be to change `property('foods@each')` to `property('foods@each.saturated')`:

```
saturatedSum: function () {
    var sum = this.get('foods').reduce(function (previousValue, food, index) {
        return previousValue + food.get("saturated");
    }, 0);

    return sum;
}.property('foods.@each.saturated')  //key @each instructs to update bindings
```